# jQuery performance Eventlistener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to enhance my UI. I have several buttons based on css classes in 1 form.

When I click on a button I currently trigger my events this way:

```
$(function () {
   var form = $('form');

   form.on("click", ".btn-form-submit", function (e) { ... });

   form.on("click", ".btn-add", function (e) { ... });

   form.on("click", ".btn-delete", function (e) { ... });

});
```

Do you know if there is a better way to register my events on the form element?

What do you think?

Thanks :)

Comment: Better in terms of...? You can chain the `on()` calls if that's what you mean: `form.on('click', '.btnXXX', fn).on('click', '.btnYYY', fn);`

Comment: Is that the same function executed for the 3 classes ?

Comment: nope different functionalities :)

Comment: The only suggestion to this snippet I've got: I *prefer myself* to store jQuery opjects in a variablename with a `$`, so in this case: `$form`. That way I can easily differentiate between a normal and jquery var

Answer (score 3):

There are alternative methods, but the code as you have in your example is exactly what I would expect. Three buttons, three actions, so three handlers.

The 'performance' part is already done, you store the form and look for the buttons.

Also, **don't micro optimize at this stage**. The code you have is fine, spend time on created more/better features and *when you're done*, look back to see if there is any relevant room for improvement.

Comment: Yup.  To reiterate, the OP is already doing it the "right" way.  The most important part is that deferred listeners are being used.  That both improves performance (in the case that there are multiple elements that match the class selector) and simplifies the application substantially: you can dynamically add/remove elements in the form and don't have to worry about adding/removing listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately ,it depends on what you are trying to do. But other than the ones already suggested, you may want to provide named functions as callback functions. So let's say if you wanted to do something recursive , you would be able to do that! This has an added benefit if you want to `reuse` that function with small to no modification.

Comment: thanks for your input guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the functions are because I'd probably make one function. This demo demonstrates the use of the `switch()` method determining which function to use by the button's specific class.

### Demo

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var selected = $(this).attr('class');
    switch (selected) {
      case 'btn yellow':
        $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        break;
      case 'btn red':
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        break;
      case 'btn blue':
        $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='form'>
  <button class='btn yellow'>Yellow</button>
  <button class='btn red'>Red</button>
  <button class='btn blue'>Blue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note: This method isn't wrong and is fine for small actions per example, but if you something slightly more complex, this will get cluttered real quick :)

Comment: Agreed (+1), but based on what OP has provided, I'm assuming the level of complexity is simple and the possibility of more functions not a concern.